# Ordering by two custom fields values

Tags: wordpress

I have custom post type called "lawyer" and I want to query lawyers ordered by custom field "surname" and then ordered by custom field "name". My query looks like this:

```
query_posts( array ( 'post_type' => 'lawyer', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'surname', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => ASC), array('key' => 'name', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'order' => ASC) )) );
```

But it's not working. I get results, but they are not ordered the way I want them to. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. It's a bit different case then my. How should my query look like? I tried ordering by one criteria and that works fine for me. But problem is ordering by 2 fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work with this code:

```
function double_meta_posts_orderby($orderby) {
    remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'double_meta_posts_orderby');
    global $wpdb;
    return " {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value, mt1.meta_value";
}

$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'lawyer',
  'post_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'surname',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'name',
        )
    ),
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => ASC,
);

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'double_meta_posts_orderby');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

// the Loop
while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use `query_posts()` ever. 

 Reference [When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)**

You can do it by using `WP_QUERY` and adding filter to `posts_orderby`

```
function custom_orderby($orderby) {
  global $wpdb;
    return str_replace($wpdb->prefix.'postmeta.meta_value', 'mt1.meta_value, mt2.meta_value ASC', $orderby);
}
```

Then Prepare your arguments.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'lawyer',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => 'surname',
  'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'surname',
            'value' => '',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'name',
            'value' => '',
        )
    )
);
```

And add your custom order by filter just before the query execute.

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','custom_orderby');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter('posts_orderby','custom_orderby');
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working - I'm not getting any results like this. I've changed my loop now to look like: 
while ($loop->have_posts()) : the_post();
but it's not giving me any result.

Comment: Changed to: while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();    but still not working. :(

Comment: try `var_dump($loop->posts);` to check its has posts or not. or try changing your meta query relavent to your need.

Comment: Noman, you was very close, but with 'value' => '' inside meta_query arrays it just doesn't return anything. Have no idea why.

Comment: Sorry, it was not working for me. I had to search elsewhere.